# Can not work with ionic and form - got directive proxy error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I just start a new project and when I try to build a form I got this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ionic/angular/directives/proxies'

my html

```
<form>
<ion-card>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Categoria:</ion-label>
      <ion-select #categoryId name="categoryId" cancelText="Cancelar">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let cat of categoryList" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.name}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Relacionado:</ion-label>
      <ion-select #tagsId name="tagsId" cancelText="Cancelar">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let tag of tagsList " [value]="tag.id">{{tag.name}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Titulo:</ion-label>
      <ion-input #title oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" name="title" type="text></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Publicação:</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea #content name="content" ></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-reorder-group disabled="true">
      <ion-item lines="none" class="ion-padding" *ngFor="let photo of pictureService.photos" (click)="pictureService.askDelete(photo)">
        <ion-img [src]="photo.data"></ion-img>
        <!--<ion-reorder></ion-reorder>-->
      </ion-item>
    </ion-reorder-group>
    <ion-button class="ion-padding" expand="full" color="tertiary" (click)="pictureService.selectFrom()">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="camera"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adicionar foto
    </ion-button>
    <br/>
    <ion-button type="submit" (click)="submitPost()" class="ion-padding-start ion-padding-end" expand="full" color="secondary">Enviar</ion-button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

and my ts file

```
categoryList : CategoryModel[] = [];
tagsList     : TagsModel[] = [];
showSubmit   : boolean = false;

@ViewChild('title',{static:false}) title: IonInput;
@ViewChild('categoryId',{static:false}) categoryId: IonSelect;
@ViewChild('tagsId',{static:false}) tagsId: IonSelect;
@ViewChild('content',{static:false}) content: IonTextarea;

constructor(private authService     : AuthService,
          private categoryService : CategoryService,
          private tagsService     : TagsService,
          private postsService    : PostsService,
          private pictureService  : PictureService,
          private funcsHelperService : FuncsHelperService,
          private router          : Router) {

this.categoryList = this.categoryService.categoryStoredList;
this.tagsList     = this.tagsService.tagsStoredList;

 }

 ngOnInit() {

}


submitPost() {

const data: PostsModel  = {
  categoryId: this.categoryId.value,
  tagsId: this.tagsId.value,
  date: new Date().getDate().toString(),
  title: this.title.value.toString(),
  content: this.content.value,
  photo: this.pictureService.getImagesArray(),
  uid: this.authService.currentUser.uid,
  video: null
};
this.funcsHelperService.presentLoading("Enviando seu post ...");
this.postsService.add(data).then( response => {
  this.funcsHelperService.dismissLoading();
  console.log("addPost",response);
});

}
```

Also I try to to do with formGroup instead viewChild, I got the same error, I delete all my node_modules folder and the lock file and install agains but nothing change.

How can I try to fix this? I never get this error before.

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade to ionic/angular 8.1.2 in my package.json and work.